# Uploading file from NodeJS and renaming to destination folder if file exists in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am uploading file from NodeJS.
I need to check if file exists in the destination folder then upload file by adding 4 digit random no to the file.

```
    let storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {

let date_ob = new Date();

// current date
// adjust 0 before single digit date
let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2);

// current month
let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);

// current year
let year = date_ob.getFullYear();

const fullPath = __basedir + "/Files/" + year + "/" + month + "/" + date + "/";

if (!fs.existsSync(fullPath)) {      
  fs.mkdirSync(fullPath, { recursive: true });
}

cb(null, fullPath);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file.originalname);
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

let uploadFile = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: maxSize },
}).single("file");
```

Please advise

Regards

Comment: You should not use `fs.xxxSync` on your server as it will block execution. Furthermore with `{recursive: true}` there is no need to check whether that directory already exists. If it doesn't exist, it will be created, otherwise this is a NoOp.

Comment: Other than that, you seem to know how to check if a file exists, so what's your particular problem?

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply. I am not expert in NodeJS. Please advise other than fs.xxxSync what should I use in my code. This code I took from internet. I am creating year, month and date folder at the runtime and then I upload the files. If the same file uploaded again on the server, I don't want to overwrite the file, rather I want to rename the uploaded by with some random number at the end. FIle extension there should not be any change. Please advise. Many thanks again.